# Removing Items From Favourite List

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on angular js on single page application in mvc arcitecture i have a list of favourites i want to delete on my click event

Html For Angular

```
<div class="favourite" ng-repeat="favourite in category.favourites | orderBy:'title'">
                <a class="title" ng-href="{{favourite.url}}" ng-bind-html="favourite.title | mlStripHtml"></a>
                <div ng-if="profileFavourites.canDelete" class="remove" title="{{ 'TaBort' | mlLocalization }}" ng-click="profileFavourites.remove(favourite, $event,$index)"></div>
            </div>
```

Angular Js

```
 FavouriteService.getFavourites(profileId).then(
  function (favourites) {
      $scope.categories = []

  _.forEach(favourites, function (fav) {
      var category = _.find($scope.categories, function (cat) {
          $scope
          return cat.id == fav.type
      })

      if (category) {
          category.favourites.push(fav)
          return
      }

      category = {
          id: fav.type,
          name: Language.getTypeName(fav.type, {
              case: 'none'
          }),
          favourites: [fav]
      }

      $scope.categories.push(category)
  })

  $scope.isLoadingFavourites = false
```

})

```
  $scope.remove = function (favourite, $event) {




      $event.preventDefault()
      $event.stopPropagation()



      FavouriteService.removeFromFavourites(favourite.id).then(
        function () {
            alert("favourite")
            var category = _.find($scope.categories, function (cat) {

            return cat.id == favourite.type
          })

          if (category) return

          _.remove(category.favourites, function (fav) {

            return fav.id == favourite.id
          })

          if (!category.favourites.length) {
            _.remove(scope.categories, function (cat) {
              return cat.id == category.id
            })
          }
        })
    }
```

The above mention is my code for the removal of item from the list it works perfectly fine when i click on delete link it successfully delete the item but the onlu issue is it does not reflect the change till the page gets refrehed i m tryingh hard but could not resolve it as i m new to angular js any help will be appreciated

Comment: did you delete the item from button inside  ng-repeat??

Comment: means i m not getting u

Comment: please show your whole html code

Comment: <div class="favourite" ng-repeat="favourite in category.favourites | orderBy:'title'">
     <a class="title" ng-href="{{favourite.url}}" ng-bind-html="favourite.title | mlStripHtml"></a>
     <div ng-if="profileFavourites.canDelete" class="remove" title="{{ 'TaBort' | mlLocalization }}" ng-click="profileFavourites.remove(favourite, $event,$index)"></div>
    </div>

Comment: u can c now i have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

you are passing $index in remove method so you can use below code to remove favourite

```
  $scope.remove = function (favourite, $event,index) {
  $event.preventDefault()
  $event.stopPropagation()
      FavouriteService.removeFromFavourites(favourite.id).then(
       function () {
        alert("favourite")
         $scope.category.favourites.splice(index,1);

    })
```

it will refresh your list.

Comment: no mam thanks for ur suggestion but i m still havin the same problem the list is not getting refreshed